# Questions on theorem proving in type-driven languages

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation

I have a small number of questions on issues I have encountered while working with the [Idris](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2) language, specifically trying to utilize it as a theorem proving language, and I am tempted to ask my question in the new [proof assistant SE site](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/). Idris, however, is explicitly designed as a general purpose programming language rather than a proof assistant, and most of my questions are essentially of *"Why won't this thing typecheck?"* form or confusion over Idris type system, similar to many questions you would see for Haskell, and it feels more appropriate to ask on SO. I would imagine this same question would apply to other similar languages as well as the rare case when theorem proving is done in Haskell with its hurdles.

Where would these questions be more appropriate?

Comment: I don't know what's on-topic/off-topic on the new [proofassistants.se], but you may be interested in [browsing 'idris' questions posted since 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bidris%5d%20is%3aq%20created%3a2020&searchOn=3) and checking how the questions were handled. (Why not since 2010? Because some of the old questions may not fare well if posted now due to the history + policy changes)

Comment: And it repeats all over again with [list of](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/1229/what-are-good-examples-of-april-fools-jokes-in-the-proving-assistant-community) [X questions](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/43/proof-assistants-for-beginners-a-comparison).

Comment: (*[Idris, Proof assistant features*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idris_(programming_language)#Proof_assistant_features) - *"...an Idris program can prove invariants at compile time. This makes Idris into a proof assistant."*)

Comment: To "utilize it as a theorem proving language" doesn't make it a theorem-proving language. You are programming, that's OK for [so]. However a particular question might or might not be appropriate. There are also [cs.se], [cstheory.se] & [softwareengineering.se]. Please show the results of your research on the on-topicality of [se] sites including [proofassistants.se].

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the specific task you are stuck on. If you know the abstract solution, but not how to implement it, or to make sure that the implementation follows the model, then asking it on SO is fine. After all, what you are doing is unique to software development. If you need help with your abstract/conceptual model, then asking somewhere else may be more appropriate.